# Bash multi-line output with spaces, as array variable

Tags: bash

I'm struggling with command output on Bash 3.2 on Mac OS X. I have a command that outputs a multi-line string. Each line of the string has spaces in the value.

I want to assign each value to an element of an array variable.

I have the following script:

```
declare -a sublist;
sublist=`azure account list --json | jsawk 'return this.name' -a 'return this.join("\n")'`;
echo ${sublist[0]};
```

The output from the `azure` command is:

```
Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN
Microsoft Partner Network
```

The value of the `echo` command is:

```
Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN Microsoft Partner Network
```

What I'm *expecting* the output of the echo command to be is:

```
Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN
```

The variable named `sublist` should be an array, with two elements:

```
[0] Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN
[1] Microsoft Partner Network
```

The part I'm really struggling with is getting each whole line, including its spaces, to be treated as a single string. I've tried many variations of line #2, where I assign the command output to the `sublist` variable, and haven't found one that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring `sublist` to be an array, but you are only assigning to the first element (`sublist` and `sublist[0]` are, for the most part, synonymous). In `bash` 4, you can use the `readarray` command:

```
readarray -t sublist < <(azure account list --json | jsawk 'return this.name' -a 'return this.join("\n")')
```

Prior to `bash` 4, you would need a loop to assign each element one at a time:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    sublist+=( "$line" )
done < <(azure ...)
```

Comment: That is a process substitution. The output of `azure` is treated as a file, from which the `readarray` command or the loop reads via normal input redirection. I use it instead of a pipe (`azure ... | readarray` or `azure ... | while ...; do ... ; done`) so that `sublist` is set in the current shell, not a subshell.